# Django-CMS reuse plugin instance

Tags: python, django, plugins, django-cms, code-reuse

Is it possible in django-cms to reuse a plugin's instance? Let's say that I add an instance of the plugin "Text" (or of any other plugin) in a page and I want to reuse the same text in another page.

This was not what I am looking for: [reuse same django cms plugin instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19801788/reuse-same-django-cms-plugin-instance) This requires to have a static tag in the template, I want to be able to use the same plugin instance in several pages (but not all) of the same template.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at snippets?

Comment: Snippets is a cool plugin, but it only gives a list of other HTML snippets to reuse. I could try and add this functionallity to other plugins, I was just wondering if something exists already that makes this feature available to all plugins. Cheers

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, Snippets are the only type of plugin where you can add the same *instance* of a plugin to multiple placeholders. It's possible to share a placeholder across multiple templates, like adding content to a footer, etc, but it's not possible to share an instance of any other type of plugin across multiple placeholders

Answer (score 2):

have a look at https://github.com/divio/djangocms-stacks/

They work similar to static_placeholders but provide a stack plugin as well... maybe a static_placeholder plugin could be developed?