# Clone plugin for Django-cms

Tags: python, django, plugins, django-cms, code-reuse

What I want to accomplish is the same as here: [Django-CMS reuse plugin instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22797614/django-cms-reuse-plugin-instance)

Is it possible to reuse the same plugin instance that was added in a page into other pages? For example, I want to have a custom contact form in the sidebar of many pages. The only solution I see right now is to add one instance in every page separately. And then the same for every language of the site..

Is there a "clone-plugin" for django-cms that does this job?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I the newest django-cms there is an Alias-Plugin. You can create an alias via the plugin context menu in structure mode. This will create an Alias Plugin and place it in the clipboard.